# Hey, I'm getting Navbar.jsx:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Text') at Navbar in React router and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, react-props

My App.jsx:

```
<Router>
<div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />}> <About /> </Route>
            <Route path="/" element={<TextForm />}>
              <TextForm showAlert={showAlert} heading="Enter The Text." mode={mode}/>
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>

My Navbar.jsx, I'm thrown an error at {props.about.Text}...:
<li className="nav-item">
              <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">
                {props.about.Text}
              </Link>
            </li>
```

I was trying to use react router to switch between my home page and about page components!!
Now my chrome dev tools console is full of errors!!

Comment: The error tells you exactly the issue, that it cant read `Text` which means that you are probably passing bad props to a component. Can you reformat your code and add the sections you have cropped out.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-chaum-qyflp5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I uploaded the components here!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In App.js you use the Navbar component with the incorrect props.

```js
<Navbar mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} about={{text: "Your text here"}}/>
```

In Navbar, change object fields to lowercase.

```js
<Link className="nav-link" to="/about">
  {props.about.text}
</Link>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks the above code worked, but I still got this error: Uncaught Error: [About] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Comment: This is another error, just remove the <About/> and all children to <Route>
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial